# JXL2 How to use Excel markup for template with multiple sheets

Tags: jxls

I have an Excel template with 2 sheets. I put the following markups in each sheet:
Sheet 1: jx:area(lastCell="G34")
Sheet 2: jx:area(lastCell="F21")
It seems like the Poitransformer only processed sheet 1. the sheet 2 is exact the same as the original templete. (the comments in A1 is still there and all ELs are the there as well).

I searched around that no one has the problem like this.

I know I could use XML configuration or Java API for multiple sheets. I think the Excel markup is simpler.

is my markup wrong or the Excel markup doesn't support multiple sheets in a template?

Answer (score 0):

Problem found. it's a bug in POI sheet.getCellComment for xls format. I switched to xlsx format solved the problem.

To summary up, for multiple sheet in a template. you just markup them the same as the single sheet. but this doesn't work for xls format.